# Mean, mode and median equal for a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose for a random variable mean, mode and median are equal. What is the intuitive meaning of this ?

Comment: Intuitively, it means that the random variable is not skewed too far to the left or right. See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Relationship_of_mean_and_median for instance.